# Unsatisfied Link Error BluetoothStackBlueSoleil

Tags: java, bluetooth

I'm trying to use bluetooth for a java application, I'm on Windows 7 64bit. 
I'm following this example

```
http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/
```

Turned out I had problem with the bluecove.jar proposed on that site, so I found this thread

```
http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/issues/detail?id=109
```

telling me to get this .jar:

```
http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.62/
```

Alright then!
But now, I'm facing a new error (yaay...):

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:     com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueSoleil.getLibraryVersion()I
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueSoleil.getLibraryVersion(Native Method)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.setBluetoothStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:964)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:502)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.access$500(BlueCoveImpl.java:69)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl$1.run(BlueCoveImpl.java:1044)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.detectStackPrivileged(BlueCoveImpl.java:1042)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.getBluetoothStack(BlueCoveImpl.java:1035)
at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDeviceInstance(LocalDevice.java:75)
at javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDevice(LocalDevice.java:95)
at BTThread.waitForConnection(BTThread.java:35)
at BTThread.run(BTThread.java:23)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So.. would anyone have any idea why?
The BluetoothStackBlueSoleil seems to be in the .jar I downloaded, so I don't get the unstatisfied link error...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing Bluesoleil from my computer and installing different Bluetooth drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that there was native methods that you needed to build. You have to compile the native code from the JNI folder using the Android NDK. ndk-build etc

Just in case you see the problem again.

Comment: The problem was on the Java PC part, I don't think this has to do anything with the NDK... Right?

Comment: I am not sure, just adding that that was my problem when I saw something similar, in case it helps you in the future. The library could not be called because it was not built correctly.